# Need help to advice how to solve using Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have 2 tables as shown below

***Table 1***

```
  AA    
  BB    
  CC    
  DD    
  EE
```

***Table 2***

```
 bb 
 aa    
 bb1    
 bb2    
 cc1    
 cc2    
 cc3
```

I need help to do the below steps using Excel VBA code

1. Use Table 1 and loop thru each data in table 1 and compare to Table 2
2. If table 2 only have 1 match, just replace the Table 1 data from the table 2 value on the same row of data from table 1
3. If have multiple match from table 2, them prompt user to select which data from table 2 need to be written in table 1

Matching Criteria are as follows

AA should match to aa,aa1,aa2,,,,,,

BB shoud match bb,bb1,bb2,,,,,,,,

Below is the code that I have written

```
   Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

    Dim attr1 As Range, data1 As Range
    Dim item1, item2, item3, lastRow, lastRow2
    Dim UsrInput, UsrInput2 As Variant
    Dim Cnt As Integer, LineCnt As Integer
    Dim MatchData(1 To 9000) As String
    Dim i As Integer, n As Integer, j As Integer, p As Integer
    Dim counter1 As Integer, counter2 As Integer
    Dim match1(1 To 500) As Integer
    Dim matchstr1(1 To 500) As String
    Dim tmpstr1(1 To 500) As String
    Dim storestr(1 To 500) As String
    Dim tmpholderstr As String

    counter1 = 1
    counter2 = 0
    j = 0
    p = 0

    tmpholderstr = ""

    For i = 1 To 500
        storestr(i) = ""
    Next i

    For i = 1 To 500
        tmpstr1(i) = ""
    Next i

    For i = 1 To 500
        matchstr1(i) = ""
    Next i

    For i = 1 To 500
        match1(i) = 0
    Next i

    For i = 1 To 9000
        MatchData(i) = ""
    Next i

    UsrInput = InputBox("Enter Atribute Column")
    UsrInput2 = InputBox("Enter Column Alphabet to compare")

    With ActiveSheet
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, UsrInput).End(xlUp).Row
        'MsgBox lastRow
    End With

    With ActiveSheet
        lastRow2 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, UsrInput2).End(xlUp).Row
        'MsgBox lastRow
    End With

    Set attr1 = Range(UsrInput & "2:" & UsrInput & lastRow)
    Set data1 = Range(UsrInput2 & "2:" & UsrInput2 & lastRow2)

    'Debug.Print lastRow
    'Debug.Print lastRow2

    For Each item1 In attr1
        item1.Value = Replace(item1.Value, " ", "")
    Next item1

    For Each item1 In attr1
         If item1.Value = "" Then Exit For
         counter1 = counter1 + 1
         item1.Value = "*" & item1.Value & "*"

         For Each item2 In data1
               If item2 = "" Then Exit For
               If item2 Like item1.Value Then
                    counter2 = counter2 + 1
                    match1(counter2) = counter1
                    matchstr1(counter2) = item2.Value
                    tmpstr1(counter2) = item1.Value
                    Debug.Print item1.Row
                    Debug.Print "match1[" & counter2; "] = " & match1(counter2)
                    Debug.Print "matchstr1[" & counter2; "] = " & matchstr1(counter2)
                    Debug.Print "tmpstr1[" & counter2; "] = " & tmpstr1(counter2)                        
                End If            
        Next item2
     Next item1

' Below is the code that go thru the array and try to write to table 1
' But it is not working as expected.

    For n = 1 To 500
        If matchstr1(n) = "" Then Exit For

        If match1(n) <> match1(n + 1) Then
            Range("K" & match1(n)) = matchstr1(n)
        Else
            i = 0
            For j = n To 300
                If matchstr1(j) = "" Then Exit For    

                i = i + 1
                If match1(j) = match1(j + 1) Then
                    tmpstr1(i) = matchstr1(j)                           
                End If
            Next j
         End If        
    Next n        

    End Sub
```

Comment: Can you show us the code that you have written?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. Your two tables are suppose to be in a sheet named `"MyData"`, where there is also a command button (`CommandButton2`). Add also a UserForm (`UserForm1`), and in that UserForm add another command button (`CommandButton1`).

In the module associated with `CommandButton2`, copy the following code:

```
Public vMyReplacementArray() As Variant
Public iNumberOfItems As Integer
Public vUsrInput As Variant, vUsrInput2 As Variant
Public lLastRow As Long, lLastRow2 As Long
Public rAttr1 As Range, rData1 As Range, rItem1 As Range, rItem2 As Range
Public iCounter1 As Integer

Sub Button2_Click()


    vUsrInput = InputBox("Enter Atribute Column")
    vUsrInput2 = InputBox("Enter Column Alphabet to compare")

    With ActiveSheet
        lLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, vUsrInput).End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    With ActiveSheet
        lLastRow2 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, vUsrInput2).End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    Set rAttr1 = Range(vUsrInput & "2:" & vUsrInput & lLastRow)
    Set rData1 = Range(vUsrInput2 & "2:" & vUsrInput2 & lLastRow2)

    ReDim vMyReplacementArray(1 To 1) As Variant

    For Each rItem1 In rAttr1
         For Each rItem2 In rData1
             If (InStr(1, rItem2, rItem1, vbTextCompare)) > 0 Then
                vMyReplacementArray(UBound(vMyReplacementArray)) = rItem1.Value & "-" & rItem2.Value
                ReDim Preserve vMyReplacementArray(1 To UBound(vMyReplacementArray) + 1) As Variant
            End If
        Next rItem2
    Next rItem1
    iNumberOfItems = UBound(vMyReplacementArray) - LBound(vMyReplacementArray)

    UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

And in the `Userform`, the following:

```
Dim k As Integer

Private Sub UserForm_initialize()
Dim myElements() As String
Dim theLabel As Object
Dim rad As Object

    Class1 = ""
    k = 1
    For i = 1 To iNumberOfItems

        myElements = Split(vMyReplacementArray(i), "-")

        If myElements(0) <> Class1 Then

            Set theLabel = UserForm1.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "Test" & i, True)
            theLabel.Caption = myElements(0)
            theLabel.Left = 80 * k
            theLabel.Width = 20
            theLabel.Top = 10

            k = k + 1
            j = 1

        End If

        Set rad = UserForm1.Controls.Add("Forms.OptionButton.1", "radio" & j, True)
        If j = 1 Then
            rad.Value = True
        End If
        rad.Caption = myElements(1)
        rad.Left = 80 * (k - 1)
        rad.Width = 60
        rad.GroupName = k - 1
        rad.Top = 50 + 20 * j

        j = j + 1
        Class1 = myElements(0)
    Next i

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim ctrl As MSForms.Control
Dim dict(5, 1)
Dim i

'## Iterate the controls, and associates the GroupName to the Button.Name that's true.
i = 0
For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
    If TypeName(ctrl) = "OptionButton" Then
        If ctrl.Value = True Then
            dict(i, 0) = ctrl.GroupName
            dict(i, 1) = ctrl.Caption
            i = i + 1
        End If
    End If
Next
'For i = 0 To k
'MsgBox "grupo: " & dict(i, 0) & "elem: " & dict(i, 1)
'Next
    j = 0
    For i = 1 To iNumberOfItems

     myElements = Split(vMyReplacementArray(i), "-")
        For Each rItem1 In rAttr1
            If rItem1 = myElements(0) Then
                rItem1 = dict(j, 1)
                j = j + 1
            End If
        Next
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi CMArg , I got an the following error "Invalid attribute in Sub or Function.  I create a sub CommandButton2_Click() and insert the top code

Comment: Open a new workbook. Rename Sheet1 as "MyData". In (for example) column A copy your Table1 values. In (say) column D your Table2 data. Go to Developer. In Modules, click "Insert" then "Module", and copy the first piece of code. The click Forms and insert UserForm. Make UserForm bigger by dragging, and insert a command button in that UserForm. Press F7 (it shows the code) and copy the second piece of code. Then go to sheet MyData, add a command button and, when asked, associated the macro `Button2_Click()`. It is working for me....

Comment: Hi CMArg, I have tried to run your code but looks like there is a compiler error. The error is highlighted on Private Sub UserForm_initialize (). What I did is after insert the command button in that UserForm. I copy the second piece of code in between sub Private Sub CommandButton1_Click() and Sub. It is correct? O got this compile error. Only comments may appear after End Sub, End Function or End Property. I have 2 subs at the end of the code.

Comment: Nope. The second piece of code is not inside CommandButton1_Click(). Once you create the UserForm with a CommandButton in it, just press F7 and copy the second piece of code. There should be nothing else. As you can see, the second piece of code includes the behaviour of the CommandButton.